# can we share generated jaxb classes for multiple webservices

Tags: jaxb, wsdl

Hi I am new to Web services and Jaxb. struggling to get it work please help me.
   we have a web service which was generated from wsdl and xsds using JDeveloper, here all Jaxb classes generated to one package which has package-info.java class with some namespace. by using generated Jaxb classes(some of them are ErrorType.java and WarningType.java) we have written some utility classes and its working fine.
   now we got new wsdl&xsds to create one more new service for other requirement. when we generate jaxbs for this wsdl all classes created into other package with different namespace in the package-info.java class. but for this service also we have some common classes like ErrorType and WarningType by using them we have already a utility class.
to use that utility for this serivice i had to separate all the common classes into one package. but the problem is, since both the services has its own namespace, in common package-info.java class i can keep any one of the service's namespace only. 
    can you please help me is there any possibility to share these common classes across multiple web services.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an external binding customization which matches the schema/namespace of the shared classes and puts them into a separate package.

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://common.schema.ns/">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="org.acme.foo.common" />
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Configure the generation to create an episode from this and include the episode in the builds for the different web services.

Check the following link:
https://metro.java.net/2.0/guide/Compiling_multiple_WSDLs_that_share_a_common_schema.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick reply. i have gone through the link, it seems if the common schema has different namespace, for ex. in service A, common xsd namespace is org.foo.common and in service B, common xsd namespace is  org.foo.common then it may be possible to generate to separate package. but in my case, for service A, all XSDs has one namespace let org.srv.foo and for service B, all XSDs has other namespace let org.srv.bar. please let me know if i am missing anything from your suggestion or link. please note we cannot change XSDs anymore.